# Apply custom styles only the parent mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I want to apply some custom styles only to the parent `mat-tab-group` without effecting to the child `mat-tab-groups`. So, I tried to add a custom class only to the parent `mat-tab-group` but it doesn't work. Is there any way to achieve this?

A `stackbitz` example of the problem :- [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-custom-styles-only-to-parent-mat-tab-group?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html)

Actual project's

- Angular Version - 8.2.14
- Angular Material Version - 8.2.3

**Stackbitz Example's Source Code:**

tab-group-basic-example.html

```html
    <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs class="parent-tab-group">
      <mat-tab label="P1">
        <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
          <mat-tab label="P1 - C1"> Parent 1 - Child 1 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="P1 - C2"> Parent 1 - Child 2 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="P1 - C3"> Parent 1 - Child 3 </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="P2">
        <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
          <mat-tab label="P2 - C1"> Parent 2 - Child 1 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="P2 - C2"> Parent 2 - Child 2 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="P2 - C3"> Parent 2 - Child 3 </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="P3">
        <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
          <mat-tab label="P3 - C1"> Parent 3 - Child 1 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="P3 - C2"> Parent 3 - Child 2 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="P3 - C3"> Parent 3 - Child 3 </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

tab-group-basic-example.css

```css
    .parent-tab-group .mat-tab-label {
      color: white;
      min-width: 25px !important;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: orange;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
```

tab-group-basic-example.ts

```js
    import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
    
    @Component({
      selector: "tab-group-basic-example",
      templateUrl: "tab-group-basic-example.html",
      styleUrls: ["./tab-group-basic-example.css"],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class TabGroupBasicExample {}
```

Comment: Where did you add the styles? Can you share your CSS or SASS?

Comment: tab-group-basic-example.css file in this [stackbitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-custom-styles-only-to-parent-mat-tab-group?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html) @Dalorzo

Answer (score 2):

I should target only the header that is a child of the top-most parent. E.g. I tried changing the selector to `.parent-tab-group > .mat-tab-header .mat-tab-label` and it worked for me.

Reference: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/21710#issuecomment-770970418

Answer (score 0):

You can using `::ng-deep`

```
  ::ng-deep {
    .parent-tab-group .mat-tab-label {
      color: white;
      min-width: 25px !important;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: orange;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
  }
```

For css

```css
::ng-deep .parent-tab-group .mat-tab-label {
  // style here
}
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't solve the problem bro. @Anh Le

Answer (score 0):

Try Using:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs backgroundColor="primary">
    <mat-tab aria-label="primary" label="P1">
        <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
            <mat-tab label="P1 - C1"> Parent 1 - Child 1 </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="P1 - C2"> Parent 1 - Child 2 </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="P1 - C3"> Parent 1 - Child 3 </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and in css add the following

```
[aria-label=primary] {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    padding: 5px;
      background-color: orange;
      font-weight: 700;
}
```

I edited you demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-custom-styles-only-to-parent-mat-tab-group-1c44os?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html

I think this will help you

Comment: When I applied this to my project, it won't work bro.